# Mapping versioning for config and infra corresponding to application code version

Tags: git, configuration-management, infrastructure, devops, scm

I have an application that has something like below structure Service A - application and environment configuration, infrastructure dependencies (Queue, DB etc) etc. Service B - application and environment configuration

Following the advise in response [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/best-practices-for-app-and-infrastructure-code-repositories) my application can be structured in either (answer 1) Git(SCM).

```
-Service A
    src
    config
    infra
--Service B 
    src
    config
    infra
```

or
Answer 2 :

```
--Service A
    src
--Service B
    src
-Config (here there are configuration common to services/crosscutting + service specific)
     common.yml
     --service A
       application.test.yml
       :
     --service B
       application.dev.yml
-Infra
     env
```

From multiples posts the general consensus seems to be to have separate code and config from the main repo. By config what I mean is say .env file for now which is different for different env.

If so then how is versioning of the 3 maintained. ie Example

```
Version 2.0.0 
App code    - src depends on AWS SQS queue
Config code - .env for App code 2.0.0 that has SQS specific params also 
Infra code  - Cloud formation (general + SQS)

Version 3.0.0 
App code  - src depends on Kafka 
Config code - .env for App code 3.0.0 that has Kafka specific params 
Infra code - cf templates (general + Kafka )
```

How can we version it such that AppCode 3.0.0 goes with corresponding config and IAC. With monorepo concept our problem is different teams doing the infra and having their own processes.

PS - I could not comment and ask on the original question since I did not have enough points hence asking as a separate question.

Comment: `our problem is different teams doing the infra and having their own processes.` is it really though?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your concern correctly. What I mean is there is a central IT team that provisions the infra based on our requirement (currently given by app team in excel which they - do not have the details but - run corresponding cloud formation templates) . The configurations to be loaded to parameter-store are also provided in excel. In order to automate the deployment, is the requirement (caveat is different versions of product is available - hosted for different customers - and hence the need to be able to tag them for a specific product release)  .